# Count the occurrences of words in a string row wise based on existing words in other columns

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

I have a data frame that has rows of strings. I want to count the occurrence of words in the rows based on what words appear in the column. How can I achieve this with the code below? ***Can the below code be modified somehow to achieve this or can anyone suggest another piece of code that doesn't require loops***? Thanks so much in advance!

```
df <- data.frame(
  words = c("I want want to compare each ",
            "column to the values in",
            "If any word from the list any",
            "replace the word in the respective the word want"),
  want= c("want", "want", "want", "want"),
  word= c("word", "word", "word", "word"),
  any= c("any", "any", "any", "any"))

#add 1 for match and 0 for no match
for (i in 2:ncol(df))
{
  for (j in 1:nrow(df))
  {                 
    df[j,i] <- ifelse (grepl (df[j,i] , df$words[j]) %in% "TRUE", 1, 0)
  }
  print(i)
}

*'data.frame':  4 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ words: chr  "I want want to compare each " "column to the values in " "If any word from the words any" "replace the word in the respective the word"
 $ want : chr  "want" "want" "want" "want"
 $ word : chr  "word" "word" "word" "word"
 $ any  : chr  "any" "any" "any" "any"*
```

**The output should look like below:**

```
    words                                                 want word any
1   I want want to compare each                            2    0   0
2   column to the values in                                0    0   0
3   If any word from the list any                          0    1   2
4   replace the word in the respective the word want       1    2   0
```

**Current output with existing code looks like this:**

```
    words                                                 want word any
1   I want want to compare each                            1    0   0
2   column to the values in                                0    0   0
3   If any word from the list any                          0    1   1
4   replace the word in the respective the word want       1    1   0
```

Comment: Why attach `tidyverse` but still use an explicit loop?

Comment: It was a mistake :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `tidyverse`(slight violation of syntax by using `$`):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
     mutate_at(vars(-words),function(x) str_count(df$words,x))
                                             words want word any
1                     I want want to compare each     2    0   0
2                          column to the values in    0    0   0
3                    If any word from the list any    0    1   2
4 replace the word in the respective the word want    1    2   0
```

Or using `modify_at` and as suggested by @Sotos we can use `.` to maintain `tidyverse` syntax.

```
df %>% 
      modify_at(2:ncol(.),function(x) str_count(.$words,x))
                                             words want word any
1                     I want want to compare each     2    0   0
2                          column to the values in    0    0   0
3                    If any word from the list any    0    1   2
4 replace the word in the respective the word want    1    2   0
```

Comment: You can denote `df` with `.` which is a bit more `dplyr` :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea, looping over the unique words to count, and using `str_count` from `stringr` package to count them, i.e.

```
sapply(unique(unlist(df[-1])), function(i) stringr::str_count(df$words, i))

#     want word any
#[1,]    2    0   0
#[2,]    0    0   0
#[3,]    0    1   2
#[4,]    1    2   0
```